# error LNK2019 in Unit Tests (CppUnitTestFramework) - C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, lnk2019, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to write 3 UnitTests.
At build I receive an error fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.
Tell me in which direction to search!

Completely error:
1>ProcessorsTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class IProcessor * __cdecl Processor_factory::create_processor(char)" (?create_processor@Processor_factory@@SAPAVIProcessor@@D@Z)
referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Luxoft_TestTests::ProcessorsTests::ProcessorAStartProcessor_NormalString_ReversedStringReturned(void)" (?ProcessorAStartProcessor_NormalString_ReversedStringReturned@ProcessorsTests@Luxoft_TestTests@@QAEXXZ)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <vector>
#include "../../../../../../Data/Cygwin/home/Nik/Luxoft_Test/Luxoft_Test/IProcessor.h"
#include "../../../../../../Data/Cygwin/home/Nik/Luxoft_Test/Luxoft_Test/Factory.h"
#include "../../../../../../Data/Cygwin/home/Nik/Luxoft_Test/Luxoft_Test/Processor.h"



using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Luxoft_TestTests
{       
    TEST_CLASS(ProcessorsTests)
    {
    public :

        TEST_METHOD(ProcessorAStartProcessor_NormalString_ReversedStringReturned)
        {
            // arrange
            vector<string> example = { "This is normal text" };
            const vector<string> expected = { "text normal is This" };

            // action
            IProcessor* pr = Processor_factory::create_processor('A');
            const vector<string> actual = pr->Start_processor(example);
            delete pr;

            // assert
            Assert::IsTrue(equal(example.begin(), example.end(), expected.begin()));

            const char* message = "TestA passed";
            Logger::WriteMessage(message);
        }

        TEST_METHOD(ProcessorBStartProcessor_StringWithPoints_CommasReplacingPointsReturned)
        {
            // arrange
            vector<string> example = { "This.Is.Text.With.Punctuation" };
            vector<string> expected = { "This,Is,Text,With,Punctuation" };

            // action
            IProcessor* pr = Processor_factory::create_processor('B');
            vector<string> actual = pr->Start_processor(example);
            delete pr;

            // assert
            Assert::IsTrue(equal(example.begin(), example.end(), expected.begin()));

            const char* message = "TestB passed";
            Logger::WriteMessage(message);
        }

        TEST_METHOD(ProcessorCStartProcessor_StringWithSpaces_StringWithoutSpacesReturned)
        {
            // arrange
            vector<string> example = { "This is my text with spaces" };
            vector<string> expected = { "Thisismytextwithspaces" };

            // action
            IProcessor* pr = Processor_factory::create_processor('C');
            vector<string> actual = pr->Start_processor(example);
            delete pr;

            // assert
            Assert::IsTrue(equal(example.begin(), example.end(), expected.begin()));

            const char* message = "TestC passed";
            Logger::WriteMessage(message);

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Are the unit Tests in the same Project as the Code you want to test?

Comment: No, in same solution, but in another Project. And test project has a reference to testing project

Comment: that's all?! ((